# Empty/Blank newform.aspx on sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, list-form

I have created a list with 20 columns and I have this issue: when I click to add a new item the newform.aspx page that open is empty/blank (no control shown at all)!

I never had this problem before. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The forms will be rendered based on the contenttype. So your columns have to be added in this contenttype. Simply write a contenttype for your table. In the List you set EnableContentTypes="TRUE" and add

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="yourid" />
</ContentTypes>
```

Now your forms should work correctly.

Comment: Hi there Maikm88.
No idea what you mean?
This is a default document lib and a list.All i did after creating the lib and the list is to add it to a page via webpart.
Can yu elaborate more on this?

Comment: Hi Maikim88,
         The only way i fixed this was to reset the masterpage and re applied it.
Didn't get to really understand what you posted earlier.Can you still elaborate on that.

Comment: I thought you created the Columns by yourself via ListTemplate. Here you must create a ContentType to ensure the Forms working correctly. (I had this problem)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but ran into a similar situation and thought the solution may help others. In our situation, within a publishing site collection, our content types were defined correctly. However, a user clicked "New" in the list and then when the newform.aspx page displayed, they clicked Edit Page and in an attempt to exit this mode, they closed the web part. The result was, from a user’s perspective, clicking "New" displayed a blank page for all content types associated with the list.

To solve, return to the newform.aspx page and put the closed web part back on the page. 
The specific steps are:

1. On newform.aspx, click Edit Page, click Add Web Part and then click “Advanced Web Part gallery and options” [lower right corner].
2. Click “Closed Web Parts”, select the appropriate web part, and click Add. (Note: In the list of closed web parts, the web part was listed as “Untitled”.)
3. Click Exit Edit Mode.