# Include information under the title of an item in a SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, title

[image]I have a list in SharePoint 2013 and my title in this is list (by default) is a link and it has the usual features (e.g. editing an item, workflow etc.).

I would like when clicking the title in an item not going to a blank page but going to a page that will include the basic information regarding this item.

For example the information that is shown when you click "edit" an item (in other words the input of the user when creating an item).

Do you know if this function is possible in SharePoint (and how to do it) as I have searched quite a lot and I haven't found actually something.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to open the Edit form of list item on click of Title? What is the current behavior in your list?

Comment: In my list, there is a column called "title". This is the title which is given as input when you create an item at this list. Once its created, the title of the item is bluish and it has the function of editing the item (you have to click on the small arrow next to it, to see the options. However, like every other column you can click on it as well. Once you click on title, there is a black page. Instead of this page, I don't want the editing function (I already have this option), I need  just to include basic information of this item (for instance all the input of the item creator).

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot or something where you are clicking and where do you want to add the item information? just to get the clear picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply but can I attach pic?

Comment: You can edit your question and attach it using image(small icon) option.

Comment: Out of box, when you click on Title in SharePoint list, it should open view form of a list not a blank page. So it seems something wrong at that list. Is this happening for other lists as well or only on this list?

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: I think with the image that I added it is more clear about what I would like to have as option

Comment: So this is happening only to this list or other lists as well?

Comment: Every list is a copy of the list as mentioned above, so it happens with every list. When I create a new one, it doesn't happen. Any suggestion? :(

Comment: @Pop_90: check whether on View Form whether webpart got closed. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46026/empty-blank-newform-aspx-on-sharepoint-2010